# VB.NET Check if the Logged In Account is Administration In Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, administration

I want to check if the login user is the built-in Admin account or not
i have many cods like this:

```
If My.User.IsInRole("BUILTIN\Administrators") Then : MsgBox(True) : End If

       or
 If My.User.IsInRole("Administrators") Then : MsgBox(True) : End If
```

or this

```
Private Function _SECTION_IV_IsUserAdministrator() As Boolean
    Dim identity As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim principal = New WindowsPrincipal(identity)
    Return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
End Function
```

But the problem in this code is when you login in regular account and run the app as admin
it check for user and says it's admin account !!

Comment: If you run the app as admin, it's not running as the logged in user.